# How to properly install package in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Recently, I installed the a package `LaravelFacebookSdk`.

---

**Install**

I update my `composer.json` by adding

```
"sammyk/laravel-facebook-sdk": "~3.0"
```

Then, I run `composer update`

---

**Service Provider**

In my `/config/app.php`, I add the `LaravelFacebookSdkServiceProvider` to the providers array.

```
'providers' => [
    SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdkServiceProvider::class,
    ];
```

---

Everything works great. Then, I pushed it to my repository.

---

**Here comes the issue !**

Second developer coming in did a `git pull` and run `composer update`

He will get an error

```
 SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdkServiceProvider::class,
```

is undefine. because, I declared that in my `/config/app.php` under my providers array.

He have to go **comment out** that line, and run the `composer update` first. After everything successfully installed, then go back in and **uncomment** that line back again.

Will other developer have to do this each time, we installed a new package ?

Am I missing something here ?

Please kindly advise if I did anything wrong.

Comment: He shouldn't need to uncomment the line, but he WILL need to run composer update anytime you add a new package.

Comment: When he run composer update, he got the error.

Comment: yes.I believe that is what everyone does. comment,update then uncomment.

Comment: Thank-you. Now, I know that at least, I don't do anything wrong here.

Comment: You shouldn't run composer update to install new packages. You should add the package to composer.json then run `composer install`. doing an install instead of update will fix this issue without editing the json file at all. @Arunu no commenting/uncommenting is required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that there is a `php artisan clear-compiled` command being configured to run before the update process in your `composer.json` file. And since `artisan` is an integral part of the Laravel app, it will complain when there's something wrong with the app code. Since you have a reference to a class that is not yet present, it will spit out that `RuntimeException`. You can fix that by moving that command from the `pre-update-cmd` list to `post-update-cmd` list in your `composer.json`.

So change this:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
```

To this:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "pre-update-cmd": [
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
```

Now the `clear-compiled` command will be run after the update process, when the referenced `LaravelFacebookSdkServiceProvider` class is present, so no more errors.

Comment: @ihue Bogdan is right about what the issue is, but I would recommend instead of changing your composer.json file you should run composer install (or update) before updating your app.php file.

Comment: @jfadich The package is installed by adding it to `composer.json` and `app.php` then it is pushed to a git server. Then another developer will pull that code but will need to run `composer update` to install the library to `vendor`, however at this point the `app.php` configuration is already in place, so what you're suggesting will work only for the developer that initially installs the package. All other devs that pull the new code will have the updated `$providers` array but no library code.

Comment: @Bogdan The other developers shouldn't be running `composer update`. They should run `composer install`. Composer update will go through and update all packages which isn't what you want when you're just getting your install up to date with the repo

Comment: @jfadich Excellent point. I was so focused on the fact the the OP was trying to run an `update`, when in fact the correct action here is indeed `install`.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of running `composer update` run `composer install`. There is no need to change the commands in your json file.

When you run `composer update` it will go through all your packages and update to the most recent minor version based on your composer.json then update the composer.lock. This isn't what you want.

When you run `composer install` it will make sure everything in your json file is installed, including packages you just added. This is what your looking for.